# AppWarpS2 WP8 Quiz Tutorial demo connection fail

Tags: java, c#, windows-phone-8, appwarp

Hi I have several WP8 apps that I want to add turn based functionality as a quiz like app similar to QuizUp using AppWarps2.

As a first step I sucessfully installed and setup the chat server app from the tutorial here:

http://appwarps2.shephertz.com/dev-center/

All worked O.K.

I then downloaded the QuizUp like trivia game from the samples page and have been having trouble getting it started.

http://appwarps2.shephertz.com/downloads/download-onpremwarp.php

1) I ran the server as in the previous chat server sample using the server files providec with the quiz game sample using windows_start.bat. (just like the previous sample)

2) Created a java project and imported the file system for the java server folder provided with the trivia game sample and added the .jar file to the build path and ran the program.

3) Logged in to the AppWarp Dashboard and created a zone and room (just like the previous sample) also added room properties IsPrivateRoom = false.
(server command window & Eclipse console now displays the zone and room just created)

4) I ran the trivia game sample in VS2013 having changed the global context variables API_KEY = "app key given when created zone in step 3 above", HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1"  and GameRoomId = "id given when I created room in step 3 above"

I am always getting connection failed while trying to connect in the game! I'm running the app on the emulator!

In onConnectionDone eventObj result type returns 6 (connection error)?

I'm obviously new with this and the sample details stop at anything to do with windows phone so I've pieced together bits & pieces I could find!

I not sure what I'm doing wrong or not at all here? Am I on the right track? How do I get a connection?

Many thanks

P.S. I'm also getting the following error in the debugger:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'm_FbFriendList' property not found on 'QuizMania.MainPage' 'QuizMania.MainPage' (HashCode=1166200). BindingExpression: Path='m_FbFriendList' DataItem='QuizMania.MainPage' (HashCode=1166200); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' (Name='FbFriendList'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')..
>   System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ListBoxStyle1' property not found on 'QuizMania.MainPage' 'QuizMania.MainPage' (HashCode=1166200). BindingExpression: Path='ListBoxStyle1' DataItem='QuizMania.MainPage' (HashCode=1166200); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' (Name='FbFriendList'); target property is 'Style' (type 'System.Windows.Style')..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no worry about binding issue,It will run smoothly.

I have replied on forum about your other queries,Please check the below link

http://forum.shephertz.com/?qa=3772/appwarps2-wp8-quiz-tutorial-demo-connection-fail

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I have commented about another problem on the original post. Please take a look when you have time :)